# How do I install modules in ActivePerl?

Tags: perl, cpan, activeperl

I want to install [SGML::Parser::OpenSP](http://search.cpan.org/dist/SGML-Parser-OpenSP/) 
in ActivePerl. Any idea what steps should I follow?

Comment: You'd have a better response if you explained that the module isn't available on AS's PPM servers.

Comment: and ask... why not use strawberry perl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add additional PPM repos to PPM, if you can find them.  The easiest way to do so is to look at [Kobesearch](http://kobesearch.cpan.org/).

For your module, it shows [one PPM for Perl 5.8](http://cpan.uwinnipeg.ca/module/SGML::Parser::OpenSP::Tools).

But if you can't find your module in a PPM that will work, you can build a PPM easily by using [PPM::Make](http://cpan.uwinnipeg.ca/module/PPM::Make).  Download a tarball of the module, unpack it and run `make_ppm`.  If you are properly configured to build Perl modules, you will wind up with a PPM file.  You can then install it with `ppm install foo.ppm` from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.activestate.com/activeperl/5.10/faq/ActivePerl-faq2.html

Comment: following this guide you cannot install the module i have posted link. By steps i mean what to download from the link i have posted, how to convert it to the required files that ActivePerl can install.

Comment: http://docs.activestate.com/activeperl/5.10/faq/ActivePerl-faq2.html#CPAN_shell seems to cover the question.

Comment: Except, the FAQ isn't what I'd F do.  For ActivePerl I like to keep all my modules managed under PPM. Consistency makes life simpler.